# Remove last line from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the last line "\n" from a string, if I dont know how big the string will be?

```
var tempHTML = content.document.body.innerHTML;
var HTMLWithoutLastLine = RemoveLastLine(tempHTML);

function RemoveLastLine(tempHTML)
{
   // code
}
```

Comment: what is last line ?? is it constant or can vary ...

Comment: After the last *new line* or the last `<br>`?

Comment: Assuming you have \n in the string, then string.substring(0,string.lastIndexOf("\n")); would perhaps be what you want

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes, everything that comes after the last \n or new line needs to be removed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
if(x.lastIndexOf("\n")>0) {
    return x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf("\n"));
} else {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if `x` contains one single line (may not be a problem depending on the exact need).

Comment: @JulienRoyer You are right. I updated my answer. Btw +1 for your answer.

Comment: Note that with this answer you need to be absolutely certain that there actually *is* a trailing space or else you will end up deleting the last line of the text.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a regular expression (to be tuned depending on what you mean by "last line"):

```
return x.replace(/\r?\n?[^\r\n]*$/, "");
```

Answer (score 4):

A regex will do it. Here's the simplest one:

```
string.replace(/\n.*$/, '')
```

[See regex101 for how it works](https://regex101.com/r/sRai58/1)

`\n` matches the last line break in the string

`.*` matches any character, between zero and unlimited times (except for line terminators). So this works whether or not there is content on the last line

`$` to match the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case the function could indeed look like:

```
function(s){
  return i = s.lastIndexOf("\n")
    , s.substring(0, i)
}
```

Though probably you dont want to have spaces at the end either; in this case a simple replace might work well:

```
s.replace(/s+$/, '')
```

Keep in mind however that new versions of Javascript (**ES6+**) offer shorthand ways of doing this with built-in prototype functions ([trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), [trimLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimLeft), [trimRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimRight))

```
s.trimRight()
```

Cheers!

Comment: `trimRight` is deprecated. Should use `trimEnd` now.

Answer (score 0):

Make the string to an array and pop away the last line.

The value from the pop is not used, so it go to the void.

```
function RemoveLastLine(x) {
    x = x.split('\n');
    x.pop();
    return x.join('\n')
}
```

Make it back to a string with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

I use [trimEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd) to remove last line of a string:

```
const text = `test
multiple
lines
`

const lines = text.trimEnd().strip('\n')
```